# For loop in a for loop - why does mine keep running?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a newbie question, I have grinded on it the last 24 hours. I've also done research to no avail, so be nice, pretty please.

I am trying to create two For loops, 1) one that subtracts amount of water drank from total water left; and 2) one that adds an hour for each hour.

My water drank loop is working, but the hour loop runs until the end. How do I stop a loop within a loop so it gives me a result each time? In the screenshot, you can see the error (it shows "Hour 6" every time instead of counting up by one each time starting at 1.)

```
const waterRec = waterStorageRec(totalWaterToDrink);

//TODO now need to plan out refill strategy based on SAGS and water drank each time
//TODO for water refill strategy, need to turn it into function or something that only gets called if water to consumer exceeds water stored at start of race

console.log(`-----WATER REFILL STRATEGY-----`);
// console.log(totalWaterToDrink, waterPerHour(raceInfo.tempHigh));

let waterHourFinal = waterPerHour(raceInfo.tempHigh);
// console.log(waterHourFinal);

//this calculates when you run out of water
let waterLeftPerHour = [];
let water = [];
for (let j = totalWaterToDrink; j > 0; j -= waterHourFinal) {
  for (let i = 0; i < raceTime; i++) {
    water = i + 1;
  }
  if (j - waterHourFinal > 0) {
    console.log(`HOUR ${water}:`);
    console.log(`You will start this hour with ${j} oz water.`);
    console.log(`Drink ${waterPerHour(raceInfo.tempHigh)} oz of water.`);
    console.log(`You will have ${j - waterHourFinal} oz water left.`);
    console.log(`---`);
  }

  waterLeftPerHour[j] = j - waterHourFinal;
```

This is the output I am getting:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz4UF.jpg)

Comment: What is `raceTime`? It is not declared in your example. It would be better with executable [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The inner `for` loop is effectively the same as `water = raceTime;`

Comment: Insert the `if` block inside the inner `for`loop

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).